# Upgrading guidance for Cedarview driver in Debian 6 - 2.6.32

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, drivers

Our system runs with Debian 6 squeeze (2.6.32) Kernel with N2600 hardware. I know the version is old. An upgrade is in later plans.

Recently, we tried connecting multiple monitors (CRT and HDMI), and we had no luck in making this display controllable and also were not able to set the resolution to more than 800x600.

On Googling, it was found that there were some graphic driver (Cedarview drivers) issues with the kernel.

I am a little bit new at applying drivers patches to the kernel, so I am 
requesting some guidance with this.

Processor: Atom N2600 with Cedarview

OS: Debian 6

Kernel: 2.6.32

**TRIAL 2:**

For last one week i am struggling to make my dual display work.
Earlier it was with 2.632 kernel and my previous mail thread "Upgrading guidance for Cedarview driver in Debian 6 - 2.6.32 Kernel" and various forums confirmed me that possibility of achieving with 2.6.32 is ZERO. .

Now the board has been updated with 3.4.106 kernel with wheezy.But, when i try to run Xorg -configure , it exits with an error message.
"created screens does not match number of detected devices"

Xorg -configure http://pastebin.com/G7sFuRYN

xorg.0.log : http://pastebin.com/68WQ8Zfv

My requirement does not even worry about screen resolution all i wanted is to control my X display like on/off

lspci info : http://pastebin.com/zBVesvmS

Board type : ATOM N2600

request some guidance and troubleshooting ideas,

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel pre-dates the release of Cedarview processors, so it's not surprising that you're having problems. Patching the kernel is likely to be rather complex though, given that you're new at it; you'd probably also need to patch X.org and/or MESA to get things working properly.

Since you plan to upgrade at some point, I'd suggest doing that first: it will give you a new enough kernel and X.org that everything should just work...

If you want to try fixing Squeeze, using the backports should do the trick; that will give you [kernel 3.2.65](https://packages.debian.org/source/oldstable-backports/linux) and [X.org 7.6](https://packages.debian.org/source/oldstable-backports/xorg). To do that, follow the [instructions](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/); basically, add

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian-backports squeeze-backports main
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Then run (as root)

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t squeeze-backports install xorg
apt-get -t squeeze-backports install linux-image-3.2.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
```

(for `amd64`; use whichever kernel flavour you've got currently).

Your old kernel will be kept around so you can easily reboot using that; if you need to downgrade X.org you can do

```
apt-get -t squeeze xorg
```

and confirm the downgrade.

Comment: Thanks stephen, other than this is there any workaround that suggest to make this work. My primary intent is to make my hdmi and crt to work. I do not require any advanced control.

Comment: I can't think of any workaround simpler than adding the backports...